While Loop Going Infinitely Long
I want the code to continue running until a user guesses the correct answer.
However the code runs something else infinitely.
public class Quiz{
    //Make various questions with correct/incorrect options
    /*
    * Suggestion
    * Question 1
    * How old was the first king of sweden when he passed?
    * Options1
    * 40
    * 60
    * 80
    */
    public static int correctAnswer = 40;
    public static int guess = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    public static void Guess(){
        System.Console.WriteLine("How old was the 1st King of Sweden\n");
        System.Console.WriteLine("when he passed away?");
     while(guess != correctAnswer){
        if(guess == correctAnswer){
            System.Console.WriteLine("Correct answer. Congratulations.");
        } else{
            System.Console.WriteLine("Try again.");
        }
     }
    }
}

I tried changing from do-while to while but that did not help.

how / when / where does guess get changed? if you compare the same values over and over again in a loop: you will keep getting the same outcome; maybe put a guess = GuessAgain(); at the bottom of the loop? note that it will also never write the congratulations message, as it will exit the loop before it gets chance to even consider doing so (hint: maybe a do / while loop is better than a while loop here)

Please try to sit down a while with a pen and some paper, and do some rubber duck debugging of your function. Especially you need to explain when and where guess is modified.

you never assign anything to guess after it was set the very first time. You need to re-assign guess in every iteration:  else { guess = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); Console.WriteLine("Try again");.

Also: not a great idea to put a Console.ReadLine() in a static field initializer.

you never assign anything to guess after it was set the very first time. You need to re-assign guess in every iteration:
public static int correctAnswer = 40;

public static void Guess()
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("How old was the 1st King of Sweden\n");
    System.Console.WriteLine("when he passed away?");
    var guess = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    while(guess != correctAnswer)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Try again.");
        guess = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }

    // when we reach the end of the loo, user gave a correct answer
    System.Console.WriteLine("Correct answer. Congratulations.");
}


If i understand correctly you say it's loop over many times until it crush.
I guess it could be because you don't reasign any value to guess after you enter the loop so the flow chart of you program is like:

you enter somthing
if correct skip loop and end program
if not enter loop
check if guess is corecct else print this
go over the loop
and again and again

so what i suggest is first to think on the flow of the program what you want it to do simple as to write it done without any code then code it
you would find it very helpful when you try to correct issues youy encounter
second i suggest to edit the loop to check only when the answer is not correct
try to think what is the flow chart i used

    public static void Guess()
    {
        //this /n gone add 2 lines down 
        System.Console.WriteLine("How old was the 1st King of Sweden\n");
        System.Console.WriteLine("when he passed away?");

        int guess = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        while(guess != correctAnswer)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Try again.");
            guess = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        // when we reach the end of the loo, user gave a correct answer
         System.Console.WriteLine("Correct answer. Congratulations.");
     }
    



